# How to shell script AT+CSQ output to serial

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arduino, openwrt

I'm in 1st time working with embedded linux powered by openwrt and 4GLTE module and atmega328p on ttyUSB0

now i can run at command and see the output just fine

but my goal is to write some shell script to run at+csq  and capture the output and send captured output to ttyUSB0 via serial connection

and then the captured output can be show in my oled

i need some advice to write shell script that run at+csq and send command output to ttyUSB0

thank

Comment: What specific advice do you need? If you don't tell us *specifically* what you don't know how to do then we can't help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the output".  at+csq is not a magical escape sequence - if the device is emulating a serial port over USB, just send those literal characters to the device: echo "at+csq" > /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, but I think you can just do `echo "at+csq (or whatever AT command) > /dev/ttyUSB0"` to send. And `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` to read. With data in your question, this is what I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

As @anishsane and others put it in the comments, I think a combination of

```
echo "at+csq" > /dev/ttyUSB1
ANSWER=$(cat /dev/ttyUSB1)
echo $ANSWER > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

is what you want. I am not sure why you would do that, though.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Sorry for unclear question my Eng not so well

But again try my best to explain a bit more

Now i use picocom in openwrt to send at command to 4glte module on ttyACM1 

And i have atmega328p(arduino like)  to control OLED on ttyUSB0

For shell script how can i redirected at command output to ttyUSB0

Comment: I edited my answer to better reflect your question. You might need to set the baudrate first for both your serial ports: `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 <baudrate>`

Comment: obNitpick bit rate != baud rate http://electronicdesign.com/communications/what-s-difference-between-bit-rate-and-baud-rate

Comment: @MayeulC Thank again for your advice